# Clustering Hausdorff distance matrix

Tags: clustering

I am trying to find the optimal number of clusters for groups of polygons.

---

#### The data

I have groups of polygons (≈ 400 polygons for each group).

Within each group, I calculated the Hausdorff distance for any pair of polygons (by using *gDistance* function from "rgeos" R package).

In this way, for each group with *n* polygons, I have an *n* X *n* Hausdorff distance matrix ([you can download some example data here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X0tkRJ-U5dyHRbPmmY88VQHYBpcyg5GM/view?usp=sharing)).

```
> head(Matrix[, 1:5])
         V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
V1 0.000000 1.2373687 1.4453863 1.3170610 1.7379560
V2 1.237369 0.0000000 0.9750136 0.9866149 0.8135667
V3 1.445386 0.9750136 0.0000000 0.6855510 0.5021435
V4 1.317061 0.9866149 0.6855510 0.0000000 0.4928460
V5 1.737956 0.8135667 0.5021435 0.4928460 0.0000000
V6 1.614730 1.3864667 1.4810296 1.3971612 1.4011815
```

---

### The problem

My idea is to classify each group according to the dissimilarity of their polygons. To do that, I am trying to make clusters for each group of polygons by using the Hausdorff distance matrices. The final result should be something like an "optimal number of clusters" for each group of polygons.

### The question

Inside the R program, do you know a way to clusterize and find optimal number of clusters by using Hausdorff distances matrices?

Answer (score 1):

Since you built the distances matrix, you can use agglomerative hierarchical clustering with the [hclust function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fastcluster/versions/1.1.25/topics/hclust):

```
hc <- hclust(d = Matrix, method = "average")
```

Finding the best number of clusters can be done with a dendrogram:

```
plot(hc)
```

Good to read: this [article explains how to use hierarchical clustering in R](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/agglomerative-hierarchical-clustering/).

You can also use spectral clustering, with the distance matrix for all pairs of points as input, but you have to set the number of clusters. You then have to run the clustering over a range of values of number of clusters and determine the best number of clusters a posteriori. Plotting the values of the internal criterion for each number of clusters, you can observe an elbow which gives you the best number of clusters.